# Should I install the ubuntu-22.04 iso and then upgrade to the latest LTS version?

Tags: upgrade

The latest LTS Ubuntu version appears to be 22.04.2. I have a Ubuntu 22.04 ISO file.

Is it a good idea to just install this file and upgrade later? What should I do to upgrade?

Comment: Whether or not installing Ubuntu 22.04.2 is a good idea depends upon your intended use. For some folks it's a great idea. For some folks it's not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you install a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system using any of the available media, ie.

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS *original* media
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS *updated* media
- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS *updated* media (or later)

and apply all system upgrades (ie. `sudo apt update` to update software lists & `sudo apt full-upgrade` to apply the found upgrades) you'll be using the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system.

If you note the various announcements, eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS you'll read

> As usual, this point release includes many updates and **updated**
> **installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need**
> **to be downloaded after installation**. These include security updates
> and corrections for other high-severity bugs, with a focus on
> maintaining stability and compatibility with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. ...

For some *flavors* of Ubuntu, eg. Lubuntu  (but it's not alone, as this applies to Xubuntu too), installs using 22.04 or 22.04.1 ISOs/media will have your system use the GA kernel stack, where as 22.04.2 & later media will have your system using the HWE kernel stack.  This however does not apply to Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 media (*which defaults to HWE for all ISOs*), or Ubuntu Server 22.04 (*which defaults to the GA kernel stack*).  ie. the installation media can influence packages installed, but these *defaults* can be changed post-install & all systems will upgrade to the latest if you're applying all security fixes/patches with `sudo apt full-upgrade` with correct sources & updated software lists.

Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for more details on kernel stack choices.

ie. there is no need to re-install. Just perform normal upgrades, and in fact if you had an installed system & had applied all upgrades, you were using 22.04.2 in the week before the ISO release date too.

Comment: I'll add this too.  If you'd had installed either *alpha* or *beta* ISOs of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, though it wasn't 22.04 before release instead being Ubuntu *jammy*, and kept applying all upgrades to your system, you'd also have a fully-upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with your Ubuntu *jammy* becoming the full 22.04 product a few days prior to release actually (when RC or *Release Candidate* stage was reached). An *alpha* or *beta* may contain some added '*cruft*' on their disk system that won't exist on released ISO installs (*files that are no longer used*), but it won't impact operation.